# How to exclude an instance variable from marshal dump

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling

My object contains an instance variable that point to a File object amongst several other attributes. Because of this `Marshal` cannot serialize it. How can I write a bespoke `dump` method so to exclude only that instance variable?

```
class Area
  attr_accessor :area
  attr_reader :several_other_attributes
  ........

  def initialize(name)
    @area = name
    @several_other_attributes = ....

    @log = File.open( 'test.log', 'w')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can very easily write a `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` method that marshals all but a specified number of instance variables. Here's a fairly generic example of something you could do:

```
class MarshalTest
  attr_reader :foo, :bar, :baz, :t
  UNMARSHALED_VARIABLES = [:@foo, :@bar]

  def initialize(foo = nil, bar = nil, baz = nil, t = nil)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
    @t = t
  end

  def marshal_dump
    instance_variables.reject{|m| UNMARSHALED_VARIABLES.include? m}.inject({}) do |vars, attr|
      vars[attr] = instance_variable_get(attr)
      vars
    end
  end

  def marshal_load(vars)
    vars.each do |attr, value|
      instance_variable_set(attr, value) unless UNMARSHALED_VARIABLES.include?(attr)
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
1.9.3-p550 :026 > m = MarshalTest.new(1, 2, 3, 4)
 => #<MarshalTest:0x007ff73194cae8 @foo=1, @bar=2, @baz=3, @t=4>
1.9.3-p550 :027 > m.foo
 => 1
1.9.3-p550 :028 > m.bar
 => 2
1.9.3-p550 :029 > m.baz
 => 3
1.9.3-p550 :030 > m.t
 => 4
1.9.3-p550 :031 > s = Marshal.dump(m)
 => "\x04\bU:\x10MarshalTest{\a:\t@bazi\b:\a@ti\t"
1.9.3-p550 :032 > n = Marshal.load(s)
 => #<MarshalTest:0x007ff73112b828 @baz=3, @t=4>
1.9.3-p550 :033 > n.foo
 => nil
1.9.3-p550 :034 > n.bar
 => nil
1.9.3-p550 :035 > n.baz
 => 3
1.9.3-p550 :036 > n.t
 => 4
```

As you can see, the instance variables `foo` and `bar` were ignored in the marshaling/unmarshaling.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Just a clarification. First you create an array of all but the excluded instance variables. Then you use `inject` to create a `hash` with the remaining ones that will look something like `{@baz => 3}` etc.. Finally you return this `hash`. If this is correct shouldn't `vars` be outside the loop?

Comment: @Rojj, nope, inject passes the return value from the block back in as the first argument to the next iteration in the block, the final iteration on the block returns the return value from the final block call, hence `vars` is recursively passed into the block and then returned as the return value for the `marshal_dump` method.

Comment: Forgot to mention, when you call inject with an argument, that argument is also passed as the initial value to the block (which is why the `inject({})` essentially instantiates vars). Read up more here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: I love this.  I cleaned it up and made it a simple inheritable class with a "marshal_exclude" that works like "attr_accessor" - so you just specify the instance variables to exclude without the '@'.  See source at:  http://marginalhacks.com/bin/libMarshalable.rb