# Bespoke Marshal and binary write/read

Tags: ruby, marshalling

I have created two bespoke `marshal_load` and `marshal_dump` methods to exclude one specific instance variable that cannot be marshalled. I have used the recommendation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876672/ruby-how-to-exclude-an-instance-variable-from-marshal-dump) question.

I am now trying to write and read the marshalled object from files. This is the original code

```
class MarshalTest
  include MarshalUtils
  attr_reader :foo, :bar, :baz

  def initialize(foo = nil, bar = nil, baz = nil)
    @log = File.open('test.log', 'w' )
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
    @log.close
  end

end

module MarshalUtils
  def marshal_dump
    instance_variables.reject{|m| m == :@log}.inject({}) do |vars, attr|
      vars[attr] = instance_variable_get(attr)
      vars
    end
  end

  def marshal_load(vars)
    vars.each do |attr, value|
      instance_variable_set(attr, value) unless attr == :@log
    end
  end
end
```

The module `MarshalUtils` creates and read strings. How can I convert it so to write and read binary filesas my objects are quite big? This is my attempt

```
module MarshalUtils2
  def marshal_dump
    dump = instance_variables.reject{|m| m == :@log}.inject({}) do |vars, attr|
      vars[attr] = instance_variable_get(attr)
      vars
    end
    File.open('dump.marshal', 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(dump)
    end
  end

  def marshal_load(vars)
    vars.each do |attr, value|
      instance_variable_set(attr, value) unless attr == :@log
    end
  end
end
```

Does the `File.write` actually create a binary file? If yes, how do I read it back and re-create the original object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking. To me it seems you're confusing [`marshal_dump`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html#module-Marshal-label-marshal_dump+and+marshal_load) with [`Marshal.dump`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) (which always writes in binary mode). The linked question even has an example.

Comment: I was actually confusing the two. If understand correctly, `marshal_dump` produces a string that allows `marshal_load` to reconstruct the object. While `Marshal.dump` does the same, but in addition it writes the string to file in binary format?

Comment: `Marshal.dump` creates a (binary) string which can be read by `Marshal.load`. They can also respectively write to and read from an IO-like object. The job of `marshal_dump` is a different one. It (usually) returns an array of objects that should be marshalled but again marshalling isn't its job. That's what `Marshal.dump` does. Take a look at the examples in the official documentation I've linked or in the answer to the linked question. I'm not able to explain it better. Sorry.